# rm -r -f doesn't delete inner folder

Tags: bash, makefile, scripting, cygwin

I have large projects and some scripts to compile them. I can't add all code here, so I'll try to simplify the problem: in the cleaning part, I need to clean folder named `directory` which contains other directory named `innerDir`. I have this bash command for cleaning `directory`:

```
clean:
    rm -r -f directory
```

When directory is a folder that I created with `mkdir -p` beforehand. When I clean, I get this error:

```
rm: cannot remove 'directory': Directory not empty
```

But when I try to enter `directory` , I see that it's empty. So for debugging, I modified my cleanning part to be:

```
rm -r -f directory/*
find directory
rmdir directory
```

(it's suppose to do the same, but here I also get the chance to see if all the content of `directory` was really deleted).
Now I get this error:

```
find: 'directory/innerDir': Permission denied
```

There are two things that unclear for me here:
(1). `innerDir` was created with `makedir -p` before the clening part, without any change to the permissions of it later in the code. Why don't I have permission to delete it?
(2).  If I try to clean again- the cleaning succeed and I don't have any permission problem. So, if I got permission error in the first time I tried to delete it, why don't I get it in the second time?

Comment: Are you running your commands with sudo?

Comment: @RamanSailopal - no. Why do I need to run with sudo?

Comment: I will use `-rm -r -f directory` in the target `clean`. Even if `rm` fails, make will continue. Just a workaround

Comment: @dlmeetei - for my purposes I prefer that make won't continue. will be easier for debugging

Comment: What file system are you using?  If this is NFS or some other network related FS, network delays and speed-optimizations might be involved.

Comment: What are the permissions and ownerships of that directory, and its container? Are you sure there is no *dot* file in it?

Comment: If you reliably can do what you need some seconds after the fail, how about a pragmatic approach like `rm -rf dir || (sleep 2; rm -rf dir)` ?

Comment: you get this error with `rm -rf` when you have read only permissions on a folder

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès - permission of 'directory' is 'drwxr-xr-+' . Permission of 'innerFolder' is 'drwxr-x---' .

Comment: @Alfe - I don't think that's a good way to handle it, because if we solve it this way, we don't handle the root reason for this problem- which might hurt us later.

Comment: @Assere- so if have read only permissions, why the deletion succeed in the second time I perform it?

Comment: Again, what file system are you experiencing this on?  Are there any other processes which might linger for a second and keep a hold on any of the files or directories (a lock, which is possible in some file systems)?  That would explain why it doesn't work now and a moment later it works.

Comment: If this is reproducible, please give us the whole procedure and materials to replay. Also please give us the OS you're on. `find: 'directory/innerDir': Permission denied ` means you don't have read access on that folder.

Comment: @Alfe - The OS I'm using is cygwin. And I don't have any other processes that keep a hold of any of the content of the relevant directory.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès - unfortunately, I can't show the code I'm using. I can only show simplified code that represents my problem. The OS I'm on is cygwin. I understand that I don't have read access for innerDir, but I don't understand why when I run clean for the second time- it deletes this directory (in which I have only read access to it - that's why it didn't succeed in the first time)

Comment: Is this delete behaviour consistent? I mean, you can reproduce it on your environment every time you do the exact same operations? And it always behaves the same?

Comment: Cygwin?  So you are using a windows system with a windows file system and on top of this a Unix emulator.  I think the windows file system is to blame here.

Comment: @SergeyAn - yes, it's consistent exactly like you descirbed

Comment: @Alfe- can you elaborate more on "the windows file system is to blame here"? 
Why the windows file system can cause this?

Comment: more likely a Antivirus is blocking the directory during the removing. Try disable it

Comment: "ls -lR" on directory would likely provide useful information.

Answer (score 1):

If your permissions are valid down the directory tree, `rm -fr directory` *ought* to work.

If you don't have read access on innerDir, then is it possible/likely (depending on running processes, perhaps) that something has written to innerDir, but the file gets cleaned up after so that the directory becomes free?

Can you give examples of permissions, ownership, and some scope of the operations happening between each step?

Could you rename the parent folder while working, and/or lock it's permissions to prevent other users or processes from altering things?